# Can you change monthly monetary shocks into quarterly ones?

Tags: interest-rate, monetary-policy, identification, high-frequency-data

There are now many series deriving monetary shocks at high frequency, e.g., Jarocinski-Karadi (AEJ:M, 2020), Bauer-Swanson (NBER MA, 2023).

These typically come at a monthly frequency. However my application is otherwise predicated on quarterly data. Would there be any issues in simply aggregating these monthly shocks to a quarterly frequency ?

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate these data to quarterly frequency, and this is commonly done.

The issue with it is that you are loosing information when you aggregate, however, if other data are not available on monthly frequency there are not really any good alternatives to aggregating.

Comment: Thanks 1muflon1. this is also my take. do you know though of papers which have done this M->Q aggregation in the monetary shocks context?

Comment: @cel I can’t think of a paper in this area on top of my head. But I do not work on monetary shocks